# Laravel 5 eloquent join based field max value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get rows from users table and join it with Articles table on where articles.user_id = users.id and articles.view is max.

```
public function scopeMostViewedArticle($query)
{
    $query->leftjoin('articles as a', function ($join) {

            $join->on('a.user_id','=','users.id')
                  ->where('a.publish_date', '<',date('Y-m-d H:m'))
                  ->where('a.view','=',?);


            })
        ->groupby('users.id')
        ->orderby('users.id')
        ->select('users.*','a.title as article_title','a.image as article_image');  


}
```

I have problem with the '->where('a.view','=',?);' part.
I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: I cant see that going in a where clause but in the query itself where you select the Max value  SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name;

Answer (score 0):

```
public function scopeMostViewedArticle($query)
{
    $query->leftjoin('articles as a', function ($join) {

            $join->on('a.user_id','=','users.id')
                  ->where('a.publish_date', '<',date('Y-m-d H:m'))
                  ->max('a.view');   
            })
        ->groupby('users.id')
        ->orderby('users.id')
        ->select('users.*','a.title as article_title','a.image as article_image');  

}
```

more info you can find in 
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries

Comment: Thank you for response. I tried it before but it says `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::max()`